# Matching with zero or more matches with rx

Tags: rx

Am using `rx` and am getting

```
(string-match-p
(rx bos ( "a" "b") eos)
"a")
==> 0
 
(string-match-p
(rx bos (* "a" "b") eos)
"b")
==> nil
```

Why is this?

Comment: This is https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2022-10/msg00574.html. Seems to be a bug - either behavior or doc. Likely the OP will report it as such.

Comment: But if this question isn't to be closed for lack of detail, please clarify it. It's not obvious what's being asked. See the help-gnu-emacs@gnu.org thread for a description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to do.  May be you meant this

```
(string-match-p (rx bos (or "a" "b") eos) "a")
```

Note the `or` operator there.

I usually prefer to write it like this

```
(string-match-p (rx
                 (seq
                  bos
                  (or "aa" "bb" "cc")
                  (zero-or-more any)
                  eos))
                "aand")
```

Note the use of operators `seq` and `or`.

I copied what you provided in to `*scratch*` buffer and I did `M-x eval-buffer` and I get this

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Bad rx operator ‘\"a\"’")
  signal(error ("Bad rx operator ‘\"a\"’"))
  error("Bad rx operator `%S'" "a")
  rx--translate-form(("a" "b"))
  rx--translate(("a" "b"))
  mapcar(rx--translate (bos ("a" "b") eos))
  rx--translate-seq((bos ("a" "b") eos))
  rx--translate-form((seq bos ("a" "b") eos))
  rx--translate((seq bos ("a" "b") eos))
  rx--to-expr((seq bos ("a" "b") eos))
```